# Angular 4 Deploy Error Unexpected Syntax Error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < polyfills.bundle.js:3 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < scripts.bundle.js:3 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.bundle.js:3
```

I get this error whenever i deploy my angular app to heroku, works fine on the local but fails on heroku

deploy url: moli-development.herokuapp.com

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly states that all 4 files are missing on your deployed server. I think you haven't ran build command to generate and place these 4 files in `/dist` location. Make sure you have below command in your deployment step

```
ng build --prod
```

When you run this command on server, what it will do is, it will generate all files including index.html & assets folder(typical depends on CLI configuration) to `/dist` folder.

Comment: The files are there ... its seeing the required files but reading an error from them saying unexpected token <

Comment: @MartinsChigoziem no, they aren't. It is returning index.html for those js files. Check network tab please.. Other reason for this could be some issue related to routing on host server..

Comment: I checked the network tab and I'm getting a 200 "ok" code from them .... meaning all files are present and correct.... so its not a 404...

Comment: @MartinsChigoziem trust me, please check [this screenshot](https://screenshot.net/ven65cy)

Comment: I have checked it and understood what you are talking about... so my js files are coming back as index.html files, so how do i correct it and make it work ?

Comment: i am also receiving the html instead of the .js, how did you fix that ??? please help

Comment: @AbhishekAnand what problem your are facing? I think better you can open new SO post.